# Using Codeigniter and javascript link giving 404

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I currently have the following javascript:

```
function updateView(set) {
    alert(set);

    $.post( "show_cards", function( data ) {

    });
}
```

I'm getting a 404 for show_cards even though I have a controller show_cards.php:

```
<?php

//show_cards.php

class Show_Cards extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load_page();
    }

    public function load_page() {

        $this->load->view('show_cards_view');
    }
}
```

Why won't this work? It isn't able to find show_cards.php and is giving me a 404. Why is this?

Comment: What is the full URL of the request that gives 404?

Answer (score 2):

Ya, because ( i think ) you didn't define it correctly.
You just have to load your controller class (i know you knew it), ex `http://example.com/`. It will load default controller on your CI (if you set it to `show_cards` controller) it will load `index()` function in `show_cards` class. And in your index, you load `load_page()` function that you have loaded `show_cards_view` view in it. 
do you really already create the view file (`show_cards_view.php`)?
I don't know where you created your javascript above. And I want to ask you. What is your purpose to create that function (javascript). it will help me to help you if you describe all your need and your purpose to create those functions.
comment it back!

If you want build a communication between view and controller i suggest you to use ajax, it will make your site more dynamic.

Comment: ya, i see. but it will be better to read (by human, for me) if we use an usual ajax writing. :D